# How do you make a gazetteer for Dedupe when individuals have multiple addresses?

Tags: python, duplicates, python-dedupe

According to the datamade Dedupe [documentation](https://github.com/datamade/address-matching/tree/sqlclass), it seems like a gazetteer needs to have clean, distinct individual-level data.

What do you do if the individual has moved, changed jobs, etc a bunch of times? Include multiple observations per individual with the blanks intelligently filled in?

Comment: By "gazetteer", do you mean "dictionary"?

Comment: No a gazetteer is data that has already been cleaned and deduped, against which messy data can be linked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know that a person has had multiple addresses than I would create a 'gazetteer' like this.

```
Address                Name      Person_ID
123 Main St.           John Doe  1
100 High St.           John Doe  1
1600 Pennsylvania Ave  John Doe  1
```

When you are match against this, you will have then have a second resolution step where you merge by `Person_ID`